# expdp from Oracle 12 to Oracle 11 locks account after import

Tags: oracle, datapump

I exported a schema from Oracle 12 to Oracle 11 with the `version=11.1` option using datapump's `expdp` command. After the import of the schema on the Oracle 11 database the accound was locked.

When I checked the ddl of the `impdp` statement, generated with the `sqlfile=dump.dll` option, I found this:

```
 CREATE USER "IAMUSER" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '...'
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "MY_TABLESPACE"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP_TABLESPACE"
      PASSWORD EXPIRE
      ACCOUNT LOCK;
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Obviously the password is set to `EXPIRE`, even though the default on the server is set to `UNLIMITED` and the account is locked, so one would have to unlock it manually after the import.

Comment: Have you checked if that user was expired and/or locked on the 12c database?

Comment: Yes. Password lifetime is set to unlimited and the user isn't locked.